# Binded ComboBox with DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

I'm trying to populate the datasource from my combobox with following code:

Here is the part where I create my binding

```
        _columnsLayoutBinding.DataSource = _myColumnsLayout;
        ColumnsLayoutDataGrid.DataSource = _columnsLayoutBinding;
        DataGridCreator.CurrentInstance.CreateDataGrid<ConfigColumns>(ref ColumnsLayoutDataGrid);
```

Then inside the DataGridCreator method call, I do some checking and populate the combobox with the values

```
        var list = (from object type in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof (FontSizeType)) select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(type.ToString(), (int)type)).ToList();
        comboBox.DataSource = list;
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
        return comboBox;
```

The problem is: When is when a replace the code where I populate the datasource with this:

```
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

            var id = 0;

            foreach (var type in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontSizeType)))
            {
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(type.ToString(), id));
                id++;
            }

            comboBox.DataSource = list;
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
            comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";

            return comboBox;
```

It works. The problem seems the value member initial value 0. Then it starts with 0 - ok. When it starts with the enum starting int(6) - Not working.

Here is my enumerator:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[Flags]
public enum FontSizeType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Seis = 6,

    [EnumMember]
    Sete = 7,

    [EnumMember]
    Oito = 8,

    [EnumMember]
    Nove = 9,

    [EnumMember]
    Dez = 10,

    [EnumMember]
    Onze = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are populating the KeyValuePair.Values with the integer value of each corresponding Enum. While in the second part you are using a counter starting at zero. Try the below:

```
        foreach (var type in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
        {
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(type.ToString(), (int)type));
            id++;
        }
```

Additionally in the first example you are using the FontSizeType Enum and in the 2nd you are using FontStyle. Is that intentional? Not enough context to tell for sure.

Comment: It was a mistake, I already corrected it. The second example, with id starting equals 0, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int id = 6;
```

This would solve your problem. Note: `var` for this seems unecessary.

For your enum you use the definition `[Flags]` yet you do not set your enum values to behave in this way. I would recommend removing this or changing you enum values. However considering this specific enum where the value represents the enum element as a number, the values must remain the same.

Here's a link which explains the correct use of `Flags`: [What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Comment: If I change the id to 6, I got exception

Comment: Hmm... In that case I would also recommend casting `type` as an `int`. This would make your code more robust as it would continue to work if you added more enum values. Are you still using `[Flags]` ?